# Area51 notification shows blue background

Tags: bug, area-51, notifications

I just noticed this:

[image]

When you got a notification on Area51, this happens (for me, on firefox 21.0):

1. The banner feeds in, totally red
2. After completing the fading effect, the bar turns blue - except for the text. This is the state as can be viewed in the image.
3. When the window loses focus, the bar turns totally red.

Is this a bug for StackExchange or is my browser doing something wrong? This occurs also with all add-ons and user scripts disabled.

> **Easily reproducable:** logout from Area51 but not from whole SE, then go back to Area51 and reload the page. You get a "Welcome back"-message now, which shows the same bug.

Comment: Probably bugs from it not being maintained. Slidey was removed from the rest of sites on the network a while ago, but was never dealt with on Area 51 because of their plans to ditch that site in favor of a new process.